# Heroku and Rails issue; database not working in production mode

Tags: database, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue when deploying my app to Heroku. The page works flawlessly in local mode (localhost:3000), but when I visit the same page with heroku, I get a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error.

The heroku logs states the following:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)

The code in the controller:

```
def week
  @bestbuy = Retailer.find_by(name: "bestbuy")
end
```

The code in routes.rb:

```
match '/week', to: 'static_pages#week', via: 'get'
```

The code in the view:

```
<%= @bestbuy.name.upcase %>
```

I ran the following commands:

```
git commit -a -m "message"
git push heroku
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
heroku open
```

I do have the gem 'rails_12factor' in my Gemfile

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where is the data coming from in your app. have you seeded your application data?

Comment: I seeded my app data yesterday, and pushed everything to Heroku, but was getting the same error. I just tried again, and everything works fine! Not sure what changed though...Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find_by` method will return `nil` if no records are found that match the condition ([docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by)).  In this case it looks as though your production database contains no retailer with the name "bestbuy".

I'd start debugging this by looking directly in the database to check that it contains the data you're expecting (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli for how to do this with Heroku).

Comment: Thank you. The issue was indeed with the database. I seeded my app, and everything works now.